# How to import folder from gdrive to Google colab

Tags: python-import, gdrive

I have .py extension files in folder and that folder i putted in google drive and now I want to import that folder Google collab then how to do because I am getting module found error.

First I tried to mount google drive and then I tried import the folder then it giving me no module found error.

Comment: this question is about moving files from google drive into colab.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have .py extension packages that I want to use in Google collab script so I am confused how to import that package form gdrive to Google collab.

Answer (score 2):

Mount the folder first (new folder will be created in content directiory, named drive):

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('content/drive')
```

Move to file to current collab directory:

```
!cp ./drive/PATH_TO_YOUR_FILE ./
```

Your import should work now!